# Object used in place of interface?

Tags: java, collections, comparator

I have

```
public class Methods implements Comparator<String> {


public int compare(String std1,String std2)
{
    return std1.compareTo(std2);
}

public static void main(String[] args) {

String[] string1={"Quan","Ha","Khai","Long","Han"};

    Methods me=new Methods();
    Arrays.sort(string1,me);// Arrays.sort(Object[] array,Comparator comp), me is Methods, not Comparator, but the Program also work well
    System.out.println("Descending in string1: ");
    for(String e: string1)
    {
        System.out.print(e+", ");
    }
 }
```

someone can explain  to me, Why Parameter can replace by Methods object in above  program. Thanks

Comment: I suggest you read `Methods implements Comparator<String> ` again and think about what this is saying.

Answer (score 3):

`me` holds a reference to an instance of the type `Methods`, which implements `Comparator<String>`. Therefore it can be passed to a method that expects a `Comparator<String>`, such as `Arrays`'s `sort(T[] a, Comparator<? super T> c)`.

Answer (score 1):

Class `Methods` implements the `Comparator` interface, so it has also the type of that interface.

Answer (score 1):

```
Arrays.sort(string1,me);
```

- sort method takes an array and comparator as parameters.

Since you `Methods` class implements `Comparator`, you can pass an object of Methods as well.

Answer (score 1):

when you are doing [Arrays.sort(string1,me)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#sort(T[],%20java.util.Comparator)) Second parameter expected by sort method is comparator which is Methods  in your case. Now comparator internally calling compare method and passing the results ultimately in first parameter which is nothing but a sorted list